# What caused SQL Server records to disappear?

Tags: sql-server-2008

MS SQL Server 2008 Standard, ShadowProtect Server Edition 4.0.0.5885 -- 
On Friday, our client discovered that records were missing from the database. I discovered that the Thursday night SQL backup contained all the missing records. User error is ruled out for multiple reasons.

- All missing records fall within an 8-day range
- The date range began 22 days before Friday and ended 14 days before Friday
- All adds and all changes made during the 8-day range are missing from 14 separate tables
- All missing records are present in the Thursday 11pm backup
- The application logs show no unusual incidents as far as I can see.

I find nothing unusual in the Applications list in the MS SQL Server Event Viewer.
We are running ShadowProtect Server to make image backups of the 2 server drives every hour. The same sort of incident occurred 4 months ago.

ShadowProtect runs an hourly backup of the database.

One theory is that the ShadowProtect Server 4 disk image software, which runs hourly differential backups, somehow caused the data loss during its 9:00 am Friday backup. I am not aware of any other activity. other than normal user accesses, between the normal 11 pm Thursday database backup and the discovery of missing records on Friday.

Thank you for you help. As you can imagine, the client is very concerned.

Comment: Just to be clear, it isn't that ALL records created/updated during that period are missing, it's that all of the missing records were created or updated during that window? You have *some* data created/updated during that window?

Comment: What eliminates user error or user action?

Comment: Thanks for the request for clarification. Yes, all records across all tables added during the 8-day period disappeared. In addition, all changes made during the period to existing records disappeared. Each record has a Create-Date field and a Modified-Date field. Queries on the bad Friday database find zero records with Create Dates and zero records with Modified Dates falling within the 8-day period. What is so odd is the the period ends 14 days before the date of the incident. All the records and modifications are present in the Thursday, Wednesday, ... backups and are gone on Friday.

Comment: By the way, we use the Simple backup model, so the log file is truncated every night with the Full backup. -- Users simply don't have the knowledge or any motive to selectively delete a date range of records and don't have the capability to delete just the changes made to existing records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We never did find out the cause of the lost records. We reinstalled the database in another MS SQL Server instance, upgraded the database to a new release, and migrated the data from the old database to the new one. That seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know what is deleting the records or when they got deleted, the database should have audit tables set up that include the usernames and dates of changes. Then you can look at the audit logs to see when reords were deleted and by whom or what process. All databases that contain business critical information should have auditing. Unfortunately, after the event has happened is too late to find out who did it this time through auditing. You might be able to find someone third party product to look through the transaction logs and at least might find out what time the deletes happened if not who. You also should be doing transaction log backups every 15 minutes or so.

I'm not familar with the ShadowProtect server, but the missing data sounds exactly like a script was run (and cacade delete was turned on) and seems unlikely to be the ShadowProtect server. If it was interfering, I would expect a more random kind of change that one that can easily be done by a sql query. Do you allow direct access to your tables?  You could have someone trying to harm the data or hide fradulent activities. Threats to the data are not always from outside sources or applications that would be in the event log. Who has access to the delete the data in the database on production? I would suspect a disgruntled employee.

Comment: The database has audit tables. They confirm that no user made any deletions. And as noted in an earlier comment, users do not have the ability to delete changes. They have access to the database only through a third party application. In addition, it is a small office with long-term employees, none disgruntled.

Comment: I could see how a restore from an incomplete set of differential backups could result in missing data, but how would a backup cause data to disappear?

Comment: Good question, Tim, one that may point me a useful direction as I continue my research. Is it possible for Volume Shadow Service, used by ShadowProtect to backup the open SQL data file, could damage the data file?

Comment: If it damaged the database (which I see as unlikely) the damage would be more random that what you described. The only person likely to be able to avoid the audit tables is the dba who could temporarily disable the trigger and then put it back.

Comment: Thank you for that perspective. I believe we can rule out intentional or accident deletions. Even someone at the console with SQL knowledge would not be able to rollback changes made 14 or more days earlier. They would have to restore an old backup and do some heavy-duty SQL queries to replace current records with old ones. They would have to do a lot of work to cover their tracks. Why go to such time-consuming trouble to do damage? I think we need to focus on non-user issues here. How could 14-21 day-old changes be "uncommitted" to the database?

Comment: Now we have ruled out ShadowProtect Server backup software and VSS. What is so puzzling is how MS SQL Server could rollback transactions committed 2 weeks earlier and only affect records written during an 8-date periond. Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose it's possible that someone or some process left some transactions open and uncommitted and the dba found they were causing problems and killed them, but I suspect you would have known if that was the case and probably much earlier. It seems unlikely for that large of a group of records over that long a time period though.

Comment: HLGEM: Thank you again for your insights. We are thinking along the same lines that you describe. The third-party database app just doesn't have the capability of causing this sort of "roll-back" data loss. Somehow the transactions during the 8-day period were rolled back by SQL Server. But how and why remain a mystery!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on VM. The error was was pointing to the database but SQL Server wasn't actually running. For some unknown reason SQL Server has stopped. It seems that VM was restarted and the service didn't start automatically.
After starting the service with Windows Administrative Tools, server was back on and the database was there